# How can I call slideDown() on an new element that renders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list and the li elements inside of it are rendered based on the number of items in an array in my backend.

As new items are added to an array, a corresponding li element is rendered and pops up in my list. Is it possible to give each new li element a slideDown() animation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use .on() or .live() depending on which version of JQuery you're using.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Ok so try this wrap this in a function

```
function doSlideDown(){
    $('ul > li > input[type="checkbox"]').on("click", function() {        

    var parent = $(this).parent("li");
    if($(this).is(":checked") === true) {
    // move to the top
    $(parent).slideUp(300, function() {
      $(parent).prependTo($(parent).parent());
      $(parent).slideDown(300);
    });
    } else {
      $(parent).slideUp(300, function() {
        $(parent).appendTo($(parent).parent());
        $(parent).slideDown(300);
      });
    }
});
}
```

then add this outside of your document ready function

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    doSlideDown();
});
```

That will update the DOM every time your run some ajax and append a new item.

Comment: I'd use .on() in that case.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rohithdm/fvfymf0b/

It's something like this. I know that it seems to work fine here but that's because the data is not being generated by the array, it's hard for me to post all the backend code since there is so much. Essentially more stuff id being added to the array and it does not get the slidedown animation.